# Unseting a list of dynamic variables in Bash

Tags: bash, environment-variables

How can I achieve the following with Bash:

```
x="search='something something' replace='something' subject=/path/path"

eval "$x"

echo $search
# prints something
# etc.

# (I am trying to do something here)
# So the following wouldn't print **something** anymore

echo $search
```

I basically want to unset the variables that were set using eval initially.

Comment: Fork a subshell, do `eval` in the subshell and once you're done, exit the subshell

Comment: @anubhava not sure how to do any of that.

Comment: After `eval`, there's nothing special about the variables. Just use `unset search replace subject`.

Comment: @chepner There are hundreds of them (not sure which will be available)

Comment: That's one reason using `eval` like this is a bad idea. A script shouldn't need to know the *value* of its variables, but it should know which ones are defined. Where is `x` coming from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Preamble:** Care using `eval` as [eval is evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead)...

Whatever...

### [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) could do this very quickly:

```
unset ${x//=*([^ ])}
```

As pointed out by [glenn jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47641122/unseting-a-list-of-dynamic-variables-in-bash/47641808?noredirect=1#comment82242457_47641808), this work only if there are no *spaces* in content of variables.

In this case, we could (very quickly too) prepare some intermediary variable (*`x without spaces`*):

```
xwos=${x//\"*([^\"])\"}        # This will drop `search="don't know"`
xwos=${xwos//\'*([^\'])\'}     # This will drop `search='blah blah'`
unset ${xwos//=*([^ ])}
```

In fine, adding this to your script will do the job:

```
xwos=${x//\"*([^\"])\"}; xwos=${xwos//\'*([^\'])\'}; unset ${xwos//=*([^ ])}
```

#### Explanation / showcase

Of course, you have to use *`extglob`* [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)'s option, if not already set:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

Let's try:

```
x="search='something something' replace='something' subject=/path/path"

eval "$x"

echo $search 
something something

declare -p search replace subject
declare -- search="something something"
declare -- replace="something"
declare -- subject="/path/path"

shopt -s extglob
xwos=${x//\"*([^\"])\"}
printf 'X w/o double quoted spaces 1st:\n    "%s"\n' "$xwos"
X w/o double quoted spaces 1st:
    "search='something something' replace='something' subject=/path/path"

xwos=${xwos//\'*([^\'])\'}
printf 'X w/o single quoted spaces 2nd:\n    "%s"\n' "$xwos"
X w/o single quoted spaces 2nd:
    "search= replace= subject=/path/path"

printf 'String containing variables w/o values:\n    "%s"\n' "${xwos//=*([^ ])}"
String containing variables w/o values:
    "search replace subject"

unset ${xwos//=*([^ ])}

declare -p search replace subject
bash: declare: search: not found
bash: declare: replace: not found
bash: declare: subject: not found
```

**Nota:** If you don't need `x` anymore, you could redefine `x` instead of populating a new variable:

```
shopt -s extglob;x=${x//\"*([^\"])\"};x=${x//\'*([^\'])\'};unset ${x//=*([^ ])}
```

#### Demo

```
x="search='something something' replace='something' subject=/path/path"

eval "$x"

echo $search 
something something

shopt -s extglob;x=${x//\"*([^\"])\"};x=${x//\'*([^\'])\'};unset ${x//=*([^ ])}
echo $search
```

Comment: The variable names MUST be extracted from x. I don't know them before hand.

Comment: @AdamSilver That's what `${x//=*([^ ])}` does.

Comment: Nice. The only danger is if one of the variable values contains a space. I came up with `grep -oP '\w+(?==)' <<<"$x"` to extract the varnames. Doing it in the shell is much better.

Comment: What if search value was 'something something' (with spaces)

Comment: @AdamSilver, try this: `vars=$(grep -oP '\w+(?==)' <<<"$x"); echo unset $vars` -- and remove the `echo` if the right varnames were found

Comment: @glennjackman I don't get the whole declare parts. Should I have it too?

Comment: This approach is good as long as there is a single string being used in `eval`. However if there are multiple then env variable being created from many strings then unsetting like this won't be simple.

Comment: @AdamSilver No, the `declare` parts are there just to show it functions correctly.

Comment: @anubhava the entire architecture of the question is flawed. We're all trying to just mitigate the damage

Comment: It's not working for me. Here's a full example: https://bpaste.net/show/d98d02b617df

Comment: @glennjackman You're right! I've edited my answer, without any fork to `grep`, this is very quick!

Comment: @AdamSilver This is tested under many [tag:bash]! Which version are you using (under which OS, distrib)?

Answer (score 3):

You can fork a subshell, do `eval` in the subshell and once you're done, exit the subshell:

```
# do this in a subshell
(
x="search='something' replace='something' subject=/path"
eval "$x"
echo "search=$search"
)

# now out of subshell
echo "search=$search"
```

Comment: Very useful but the script isn't structured in a way to accept this solution.

Comment: Can you clarify how do you want it to be structured?

Comment: @AdamSilver The script you posted in your question is. Can you update it?